# Samsung Note 5: Heimdall recovery flash completes, but device stuck "Downloading..."

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, twrp, lineageos, heimdall

I downloaded TWRP from [twrp.me](https://dl.twrp.me/klte), and ran

`heimdall flash --RECOVERY recovery.img --no-reboot`

On my Samsung S5 that was in Download Mode. `heimdall` seems to have completed successfully:

```
Heimdall v1.4.2

Copyright (c) 2010-2017 Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Uploading RECOVERY
100%
RECOVERY upload successful

Ending session...
Releasing device interface...
```

But the phone remains in this state:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/0Lpv2B6.png]

Notice the download bar is about 99% of the way there. Forcing a reboot to the phone from this state makes it stuck on the "Samsung" loading screen.

Edit:
Product name is `SM-N920C`, CA_ type is `CA_2`.

How might I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen if you download the wrong `twrp` - I had downloaded the S5 twrp. The only other thing to note is when in the stuck `Downloading...` screen, you can hold Power + Volume Down button to turn off the device.